# Office365 weblink @odata response url for drafts not working

Tags: email, office365

I am using the Office365 Rest API's to integrate with our application. 
Our application generates emails via templates, and then we need to open it as a draft in outlook so the user can make any adjustments before sending it.

The creation of emails is working just fine, and we get the @odata response.
In this response we are taking the weblink section and using this to open the draft email.

If we just use the section as is, the draft email is displayed in a new window, but there is no option there to send it, just to continue editing or discard. So the user has to select continue editing to be able to send it. This would be more useful of you could Is there an option to go straight to the editor? There is a viewmode parameter, but I couldn't find any information on it and trying anything other than viewmodel=ReadMessageItem just gave me a blank screen.

What we really want to be able to do is open the draft in the full outlook editor. From the documentation, this appears to be possible by adding ispopout=0 to the weblink (as mentioned in the resource reference for message). When we do this, the link does open the main outlook window, but it doesn't open the draft in the message pane, just displays the inbox. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

WebLink property provides you a URL for Outlook Web App window to read a mail the user has received, or a draft as if it was saved by the user.  So, the user does have to click on "Edit" to make any changes or send the message.  For your scenario, taking the user directly to the draft in "Edit" mode makes sense to avoid the extra click.  We will add this feature to our backlog.

"ispopout=0" isn't yet supported and I don't have a timeline to share right now.  This is intended for the user to land in Outlook Web App with the message displayed in Preview pane.  More importantly, we require the URL returned in WebLink to be used as is, as it can change.  So, if an app makes changes to the URL before using it, it could break in the future if the URL structure changes.